# How to update a Foreach-Object attribute in a catch block

Tags: powershell

I have a foreach-object loop going against an Array of data with a Try/catch being performed on a command.

I am updating items in the array (similar to this)

```
$arr = @(
    [PSCustomObject]@{Name = "David";  Article = "TShirt"; Error = ""}
    [PSCustomObject]@{Name = "Eduard"; Article = "Trouwsers"; Error = ""}
)

$arr | foreach-object { $_.name += "a"}
```

To recreate the error/issue this test command works

```
$arr | foreach-object {
    try {
        $createResponse = test-path -type $_.name
    } Catch {
        $_.Error = "Failed"
    }
}
```

When an error is thrown in a try/catch the $_ object becomes the error. Is there a way to update the foreach object still?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: the `catch` block can hold more than just that one line ... so add a line that saves the value [perhaps a `-PipelineVariable`] before the `try` and then use it to modify your object _after_ the `catch` block.

Comment: Or use a foreach loop --> `foreach ($obj in $arr) { ... $obj.Error = 'something' }`

Comment: both of these does exactly what I needed. Want to post it as an answer and I'll upvote? (Adminofthings exactly what I was looking for.) (Lee_dailey I learned something new and will use this in the future as it appears to be very useful.) Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could choose to iterate through your objects with a `foreach` loop and preserve `$_` for the current error instance.

```
$arr = @(
    [PSCustomObject]@{Name = "David";  Article = "TShirt"; Error = ""}
    [PSCustomObject]@{Name = "Eduard"; Article = "Trouwsers"; Error = ""}
)
foreach ($obj in $arr) {
    try {
        # some code that may produce a terminating error
    } Catch {
        $obj.Error = "Failed"
        $_ # ErrorRecord object
    }
}
```

Within your `catch` block, you could have a `continue` statement to immediately process the next item in the `$arr` collection. You could also have a `break` statement to break out of the loop. Neither are necessary but create flexibility.

When a terminating error happens an exception is generated. If that happens in a `Try` script block, it can be caught. `$_` or `$PSItem` will be the `ErrorRecord` object of the caught exception in the `Catch` script block.